# How can I get packet loss information from python mininet pings?

Tags: python, sdn, mininet, icmp, packet-loss

Using the Python Mininet API, I'm sending a single ping.

```
ploss = net.ping(hosts=[node1, node2])
```

This prints to the console the results of packets lost/received:

```
h1 -> h2 
h2 -> h1 
*** Results: 0% dropped (2/2 received)
```

However, nothing is returned. ploss is None. I need to store that information to validate after ping is made. How can I accomplish this?